# Elasticsearch reindex fails with _version error

Tags: elasticsearch, reindex

I'm using Elasticsearch version 5.5.

I have my index A with mapping:

```
{
  "myobj": {
    "enabled": false
}
```

I've created index B with mapping:

```
{
  "myobj": {
    "_all": {"enabled": false},
    "properties": {
      "mykey": {"type": "keyword"}
    }
  }
}
```

When I call the reindex api with body:

```
{
  "source": {
    "index": "a"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "b"
  }
}
```

I get the error: `Cannot generate dynamic mappings of type [_version] for [_version]`

Here are the reindex request bodies I've tried:

```
{
  "source": {
    "index": "a"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "b",
    "version_type": "internal"
  }
}
```

==> `Cannot generate dynamic mappings of type [_version] for [_version]`

---

```
{
  "source": {
    "index": "a"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "b",
    "version_type": "external"
  }
}
```

==> `Cannot generate dynamic mappings of type [_version] for [_version]`

---

```
{
  "source": {
    "index": "a"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "b"
  },
    "script": {
      "inline": "ctx._version = ctx._source.remove(\"_version\")"
    }
}
```

==> `[myobj][1]: version conflict, current version [-1] is different than the one provided [1507030478]`

---

What am I doing wrong and how can I reindex these documents?

**EDIT**

I've since tried adding `"conflicts": "proceed"` which simply resulted in no documents being reindexed.

I also added `"index.mapper.dynamic": false` to the index B's settings with no observable change in the results.

Comment: Have you tried with "conflicts": "proceed",

Comment: It did not help.

Answer (score 0):

There are some "reserved" fields in ES you can not directly reindex, such as `_id`, `_version` or `_index`. (and the deprecated `_type`)

Try this body in your `reindex` to remove those reserved fields.

```
{
    'source': { ... },
    'dest': { ...  },
    "script": {
        'inline': 'ctx._source.remove("_id");ctx._source.remove("_version");'
    }

}
```